# How to access activation config property value specified in ejb-jar.xml from MDB

Tags: weblogic

We are using ejb-jar.xml to configure the MDB as mentioned below. We need to access one of the activation config property "subscriptionName" in MDB.

```
 <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>InboundListener</ejb-name>
        <!--Class whose MDB instance with above name will be created by EJB container-->
        <ejb-class>com.xyz.listener.InboundListener</ejb-class>
        <activation-config>
            <activation-config-property>
                <!--The type of JMS resource this instance will be accessing-->
                <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Topic</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>subscriptionName</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>OXI145937</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
        </activation-config>
 </message-driven>
```

How to get the value of subscriptionName property in MDB's onMessage() method.

Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Comment: @user3808335, nope. Please share if you have any info